# Hide VSTS (VisualStudio.com) GIT Branches

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I've recently moved my Visual Studio Team Systems (VSTS) repo from TFVC to GIT. I am keeping my `master` branch as the one that will have PROD passwords to stuff (`Web.Release.config`) that I do not want my developers seeing. How can I lock down the `master` so that only I, the VSTS "owner", can even see that it exists, but much more so, see the contents of (browse, clone, merge from) the `master` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fork it.

For example, your master branch is a git repository that only your owner has access to.

You fork that repository into another repository, then do merges between the two repositories.

The merging between forks probably is not supported through VSTS and would need to be done through a 3rd party tool.

Comment: This seems like more of what I was looking for... here's a guide to how to do it http://www.woodcp.com/2014/01/how-to-fork-git-repositories-on-visual-studio-online/

Also, vote this feature up: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10967967-vsts-personal-git-repositories-for-forking

Answer (score 5):

> How can I lock down the master so that only I, the VSTS "owner", can even see that it exists

- a/ You don't. Ideally, you don't store password or any sensitive data in a Git repo. At all. You would use a **[vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)** for that.
  See also (initially for docker, but applicable in your case too) "**[Secrets and LIE-abilities: The State of Modern Secret Management (2017)](https://medium.com/on-docker/secrets-and-lie-abilities-the-state-of-modern-secret-management-2017-c82ec9136a3d#.jeoknukgl)**" from **[Jeff Nickoloff](https://twitter.com/allingeek)**.
  As [James Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568475/james-reed) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314825/hide-vsts-visualstudio-com-git-branches/42316427#comment71793696_42316427), the task manager part of VSTS (TFS build) would allow to [store secrets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables)
- b/ If you really have to, then at least would would store it in a private repo, that you own and that you alone can clone. Another separate "dev" repo would be reserved for development, to be cloned in full.
  During deployment, you can fetch the dev repo and the secret repo, and checkout sensitive information there (that is, in the production environment).
  As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314825/hide-vsts-visualstudio-com-git-branches/42316427#comment71791781_42316427)  by [Luca Cappa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5717003/luca-cappa), both repos can be linked together (the secret one knowing about the `dev` one) through **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

Comment: The idea remains: in a distributed repo management like Git, you don't "lock a branch": if you can clone a repo, you can clone *all* of the repo.

Comment: perhaps it is worth mentioning that the 'private repo' could reference the 'dev repo' as a submodule, and that during the deployment the 'private repo' is cloned (and from there the deployment starts)

Comment: Just to add, in VSTS and TFS build v.next you can [store secrets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables) as variables in the build / deployment process and pass them in at deployment time

Comment: @LucaCappa Thank you: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @JamesReed Thank you: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.